# TDD at big technology companies - any evidence?

Tags: tdd

Does anyone have any evidence of TDD being used at any big technology companies - e.g. Apple, Microsoft, Facebook?

Perhaps there's someone that's worked in one of these big companies that can shed some light on how TDD is used there.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of evidence is here, I started a site just about that.  [WeDoTDD.com](http://WeDoTDD.com), hope you enjoy!

It's not only evidence, it's recent evidence and includes stories behind the teams doing it at those companies.  The list will just keep growing so revist it often.

There has always been quite a few companies that TDD, you just didn't know about them.  Well now everyone can discover this a little bit easier on our site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this paper

"Realizing quality improvement through test driven development: results and experiences of four industrial Teams"

http://www.msr-waypoint.net/en-us/groups/ese/nagappan_tdd.pdf